# Android Progress Bar reset and start over on some score value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar

I´m making a simple game where user clicks and score will increase its value. If score is on some point like 200, beast will evolve on different imageView and so on.

Problem is that if I reach point in my if statement it works but when I change activity by clicking upper button and then change it back to the mainActivity Progress bar change its state to different value, than i click and it shows correct filling.

How can it be fixed? I need also progress saves itself and fill the bar after closing and opening the app.... I have Score and Proggress values saved in SharedPreferences so i don´t know where is problem. (sorry for EN). Adding some pictures to make it easier to understand.

[image: how it works]

**My Main Activity's code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    int score;
    int progress = score;
    ImageButton beast;
    SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(15, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    ProgressBar mProgress;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
    private ImageView mScanner;
    private Animation mAnimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        final int soundDd = sp.load(this, R.raw.menu, 1);


        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        mProgress.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
                Color.rgb(0, 199, 140), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        mProgress.setScaleY(5f);


        fontChange();
        addIntegerValue();

        mScanner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageChanger);
        mScanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.05f);
        mAnimation.setDuration(2000);
        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(- 1);
        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        mScanner.setAnimation(mAnimation);


        score = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("value", score);

        TextView ts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        beast = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.beastButton);
        beast.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);


        if (progress >= 0 && progress <= 199)
        {

            mProgress.setMax(200);

            mScanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.worm);

        }
        if (progress >= 200 && progress <= 399)
        {

            mProgress.setMax(400);

            mScanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.worm);

        }
        if (progress >= 400 && progress <= 599)
        {

            mProgress.setMax(600);

            mScanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.worm);

        }
        if (progress >= 600 && progress <= 799)
        {

            mProgress.setMax(800);

            mScanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.worm);
        }


        beast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                sp.play(soundDd, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BeastSelect.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }


    public void fontChange()
    {
        //font set
        TextView ts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        TextView tl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLadder);
        TextView tb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBeast);
        TextView te = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textevolve);

        int low = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("value", score);

        mProgress.setProgress(low);


        ts.setText("SCORE : " + " " + df.format(low));
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Phage Regular.otf");
        ts.setTypeface(custom_font);
        tl.setTypeface(custom_font);
        tb.setTypeface(custom_font);
        te.setTypeface(custom_font);
        //font set over
    }


    public void addIntegerValue()
    {
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        rl.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);

        final TextView ts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        final int soundId = sp.load(this, R.raw.coin, 1);


        rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                score++;

                mProgress.setProgress(score);
                sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

                ts.setText("SCORE : " + " " + df.format(score));

                if (progress >= 0 && progress <= 199)
                {

                    mProgress.setMax(200);

                    mScanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.worm);

                }
                if (progress >= 200 && progress <= 399)
                {

                    mProgress.setMax(400);

                    mScanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.worm);

                }
                if (progress >= 400 && progress <= 599)
                {

                    mProgress.setMax(600);

                    mScanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.worm);

                }
                if (progress >= 600 && progress <= 799)
                {

                    mProgress.setMax(800);

                    mScanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.worm);
                }


            }

        });


    }


    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt("value", score).apply();

    }


    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        sp.release();
        sp = null;
    }

}
```

**My Second Activity's code:**

```
public class BeastSelect extends Activity
{

    ImageButton back;
    SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beast_select);

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        final int soundDd = sp.load(this, R.raw.menu, 1);

        back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBack);
        back.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
        fontChange();


        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sp.play(soundDd, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(b);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
        {
            // do something on back.
            Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    public void fontChange()
    {
        //font set
        TextView hd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beasttext);
        TextView cm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textcommon);
        TextView tm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textmedium);
        TextView pr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textpro);


        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Phage Regular.otf");
        hd.setTypeface(custom_font);
        cm.setTypeface(custom_font);
        tm.setTypeface(custom_font);
        pr.setTypeface(custom_font);
        //font set over
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your activity onResume method do this:

```
mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
score = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("value", score);
mProgress.setProgress(score);
```

Comment: Now it is working thank you, but my if statement doesnt work now i reach 200 and progress bar max is still 200. hmm

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what you've asked. please write it in better way

Comment: Sorry, i wrote it like an idiot.... So i have some if statements in main activity and onclick.. and they´re making progressbar maximum value higher each time player reach some value lets say if I reach 200 score progress bar maximum must increase to 400 .. but when I added your piece of code (wich solves my problem with upgrading) that if statement doesnt work. So when I reach now score 200 progressbar is full and not increasing to 400... so i think whole If statement is broken somehow.

Comment: try put them in onResume too, i suggest refactor these if statement as a method

Comment: **Still not working I created ifStatements method for that if and still not working :/**                                                                                          `public void onResume() {  
        super.onResume();  
       mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);  
       score =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("value", score);  
       mProgress.setProgress(score);  
      ifStatements();`  
   }`